# Beginners Sql Sum Function

Tags: sql, database, sum

I have a table called Customer which contains two columns called opening_amt and receive_amt. I wish to display all customer details where the sum of `opening_amt` and  `receive_amt` is greater than 15000.

```
select *
from Customer
where opening_amt  > 15000;
```

works for just the opening amt, however this function does not work.

```
select *
from Customer
where opening_amt and receive_amt > 15000 ;
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the amount for both columns!

```
select * from Customer where opening_amt > 15000 and receive_amt > 15000
```

or

"sum of opening_amt and  receive_amt is greater than 15000."

```
select * from Customer where opening_amt + receive_amt > 15000
```

Both examples above are doing quite different things. One is ensuring that only customers with both amounts are greater than 15000 will be returned. The second will only return customers with the sum of both over 15000.

Comment: Is there a way in which I can query the total of both? As in I only want to see Customers who's combined opening_amt and receive_amt total is greater then 15000 (I realise your solution will give the correct answer, just in terms of diferent types of queries) Regards

Comment: Not sure if that helped ?

Comment: Sorry for late response! that's great appreciate it bud!